# SQL query where time < time now

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a question about a SQL query. I have a row in database which is called starting_time (timestamp). I would like to select every row from the table where the starting_time is in the future (later then the time now).

I tried the following query, but that doesn't work. (I am aware of the mysql function instead of mysqli).

```
$lsel_select = mysql_query("select * from table WHERE startingtime < $time(now) order by id desc");
while ($select = mysql_fetch_array($lsel_lijst)) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL function `NOW()` returns the current time. So compare with that.

```
WHERE starting_time > NOW()
```

Since you want times in the future, not the past, you should use `>`, not `<`.

Comment: He said "where starting_time is in the future"

Answer (score 0):

Try this`"select * from table WHERE startingtime < NOW() order by id desc"`

Answer (score 0):

Try This one:

$lsel_select = mysql_query("select * from table WHERE startingtime < ".time()." order by id desc");

Dont forget to accept ans if it helps